# Stop setTimeout delaying first run

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, settimeout

So I'm creating a script which adds clouds floating across the page on my website. However as seen in [this example](http://jordanadams.github.com), the first cloud's appearance is delayed (10-12 seconds) by the `setTimeout` in `spawn_cloud_loop`. Is there any way to force the first cloud to be added instantly without the delay. I have tried adding `add_cloud();` before `spawn_cloud_loop();` but the delay is still there. The project as a whole can be found at https://github.com/JordanAdams/jordanadams.github.com and the code for the cloud effect in `js/clouds.js`.

---

Jordan

Comment: Can't see any clouds in [your example](http://jordanadams.github.com/) - is this IE only, or wrong link? Anyway post relevant code **here** we can't count on external sources.

Comment: @ShadowWizard, you will have to wait at least 10 seconds, for the first one, hence the OP want it faster.

Comment: @ShadowWizard - Did you bother to actually read the post. The appearance of the clouds is delayed (which is the entire issue). This delay ranges between 10 and 12 seconds.

Comment: You never said 10 seconds, I thought it's short delay.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `clouds.js` script is included in the head and then `add_cloud();` is run immediately. Which means you create a new cloud and try to append it to the "clouds" div which doesn't exist because it hasn't been parsed yet. The second and subsequent clouds are created OK because the `spawn_cloud_loop()` function has such a long delay that the document has been parsed by the then.

You need to either move the clouds.js script inclusion down somewhere below the "clouds" div in your page source or put the `add_cloud();` call in a document ready handler so that it isn't executed until after the "clouds" div has been parsed:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    add_cloud();
    spawn_cloud_loop();
    clean_up();
});
```

Note: you wouldn't need the initial call to `add_cloud()` if you modified your `spawn_cloud_loop()` to call `add_cloud()` before setting the timeout:

```
function spawn_cloud_loop () {
    add_cloud();
    setTimeout(spawn_cloud_loop, rand(10000, 12000));
}
```

(Of course you'd still need to call `spawn_cloud_loop()` from a document ready.)

Also, you wouldn't need a `clean_up()` process at all if you delete each cloud immediately at the end of the animation from the [jQuery `.animate()` method's](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) complete callback:

```
cloud.animate({ left: window.screen.width+100 },
              50000,
              'linear',
              function(){ $(this).remove(); });
```

Comment: This worked perfectly and you explained it perfectly. Thanks :)

Comment: Some more improvements can be made, here is [live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/YQEKx/) - @Jordan FYI as well..